# How do I reuse query results in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What I would like to do is run a query, for example:

```
SELECT RouterCallKey
FROM Termination_Call_Detail
WHERE DateTime > CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

I then would like to use the information in the `RouterCallKey` column for the following query:

```
SELECT EnterpriseName
FROM Termination_Call_detail
INNER JOIN Agent
ON Termination_Call_Detail.AgentSkillTargetID = Agent.SkillTargetID
WHERE RouterCallKey = $Data from 1st query.
```

I would prefer not to use a stored procedure, I want to be able to transport the query easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to use results from one query in another is a subquery:

```
WHERE RouterCallKey IN
    (
    SELECT RouterCallKey
    FROM Termination_Call_Detail
    WHERE DateTime > CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
    )
```

Comment: Thank you For your reply Andomar,  

I don't quite understand, are you saying I would replace my query with everything you have written or just the 2nd paragraph?  If so, that would not achieve what i'm looking to do in my first query..